# Add a table of contents into a moderncv document

Tags: table-of-contents, moderncv

It seems that the class moderncv doesn't implement the `\tableofcontents` command.

Is there any easy way to add a table of contents into the first page of the CV. Within a `minipage` for example ?

Comment: Are you sure you *want* to do this? I guess conventions differ, but I've never seen a CV with a ToC...

Comment: Well, it depends. In academia in France we do CVs with more than 10 pages this is why I want to add the TOC

Comment: Wow. Here academic CVs are certainly longer than elsewhere but 10 pages would still be extremely long, I think. I get the impression that when people have more to say, they just abbreviate. E.g. Publications -> Recent Publications or whatever. But maybe for senior jobs, people put in CVs this long. I guess I've seen some long ones just for lists of publications. But then it is not clear a ToC would help...

Comment: This is great, thanks. Any idea about how to get it to display subsections in the TOC as well?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The class doesn't define many of the commands involved in the creation of a ToC (since, it's not usual to have a CV with a ToC), but providing the missing definitions, you could get your ToC.

Below I present two options; the first one, a two column ToC (produced with the help of `multicol`), and the second one, a ToC in the style of a paragraph (produced with the help of `titletoc`).

The first option; a two column ToC:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}

\makeatletter
\setlength\columnsep{20pt}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\newcommand\@pnumwidth{1.5em}
\newcommand\contentsname{Contents}
\newcommand\tableofcontents{%
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}}
\begin{multicols}{2}[\section*{\contentsname}]
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}}
    \@starttoc{toc}%
\end{multicols}
    }
\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{sm}{%
  \par\addvspace{2.5ex}%
  \phantomsection{}% reset the anchor for hyperrefs
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\vskip0pt}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#2}%
  \parbox[t]{\hintscolumnwidth}{\strut\raggedleft\raisebox{\baseletterheight}{\color{color1}\rule{\hintscolumnwidth}{0.95ex}}}%
  \hspace{\separatorcolumnwidth}%
  \parbox[t]{\maincolumnwidth}{\strut\sectionstyle{#2}}%
  \par\nobreak\addvspace{1ex}\@afterheading}% to avoid a pagebreak after the heading
\newcommand*\l@section[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\z@
    \addpenalty\@secpenalty
    \addvspace{1.0em \@plus\p@}%
    \setlength\@tempdima{1.5em}%
    \begingroup
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      \leavevmode
      \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
      \hskip -\leftskip
      #1\nobreak\hfil \nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss\itshape #2}\par
    \endgroup
  \fi}
\newcommand*\l@subsection[2]{}

\makeatother

\name{John}{Doe}
\title{Title}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle
\tableofcontents

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}  % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

\section{Master thesis}
\cvitem{title}{\emph{Title}}
\cvitem{supervisors}{Supervisors}
\cvitem{description}{Short thesis abstract}

\section{Experience}
\subsection{Vocational}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{General description no longer than 1--2 lines.\newline{}%
Detailed achievements:%
\begin{itemize}%
\item Achievement 1;
\item Achievement 2, with sub-achievements:
  \begin{itemize}%
  \item Sub-achievement (a);
  \item Sub-achievement (b), with sub-sub-achievements (don't do this!);
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Sub-sub-achievement i;
    \item Sub-sub-achievement ii;
    \item Sub-sub-achievement iii;
    \end{itemize}
  \item Sub-achievement (c);
  \end{itemize}
\item Achievement 3.
\end{itemize}}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{Description line 1\newline{}Description line 2}
\subsection{Miscellaneous}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{Description}

\section{Languages}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 1}{Skill level}{Comment}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 2}{Skill level}{Comment}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 3}{Skill level}{Comment}

\section{Computer skills}
\cvdoubleitem{category 1}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 4}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}
\cvdoubleitem{category 2}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 5}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}
\cvdoubleitem{category 3}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 6}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}

\section{Interests}
\cvitem{hobby 1}{Description}
\cvitem{hobby 2}{Description}
\cvitem{hobby 3}{Description}

\section{Extra 1}
\cvlistitem{Item 1}
\cvlistitem{Item 2}
\cvlistitem{Item 3. This item is particularly long and therefore normally spans over several lines. Did you notice the indentation when the line wraps?}

\section{Extra 2}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 1}{Item 4}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 2}{Item 5\cite{book1}}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 3}{Item 6. Like item 3 in the single column list before, this item is particularly long to wrap over several lines.}

\section{References}
\begin{cvcolumns}
  \cvcolumn{Category 1}{\begin{itemize}\item Person 1\item Person 2\item Person 3\end{itemize}}
  \cvcolumn{Category 2}{Amongst others:\begin{itemize}\item Person 1, and\item Person 2\end{itemize}(more upon request)}
  \cvcolumn[0.5]{All the rest \& some more}{\textit{That} person, and \textbf{those} also (all available upon request).}
\end{cvcolumns}

% Publications from a BibTeX file without multibib
%  for numerical labels: \renewcommand{\bibliographyitemlabel}{\@biblabel{\arabic{enumiv}}}% CONSIDER MERGING WITH PREAMBLE PART
%  to redefine the heading string ("Publications"): \renewcommand{\refname}{Articles}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{publications}                        % 'publications' is the name of a BibTeX file

% Publications from a BibTeX file using the multibib package
%\section{Publications}
%\nocitebook{book1,book2}
%\bibliographystylebook{plain}
%\bibliographybook{publications}                   % 'publications' is the name of a BibTeX file
%\nocitemisc{misc1,misc2,misc3}
%\bibliographystylemisc{plain}
%\bibliographymisc{publications}                   % 'publications' is the name of a BibTeX file

\clearpage
%-----       letter       ---------------------------------------------------------
% recipient data
\recipient{Company Recruitment team}{Company, Inc.\\123 somestreet\\some city}
\date{January 01, 1984}
\opening{Dear Sir or Madam,}
\closing{Yours faithfully,}
\enclosure[Attached]{curriculum vit\ae{}}          % use an optional argument to use a string other than "Enclosure", or redefine \enclname
\makelettertitle

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis ullamcorper neque sit amet lectus facilisis sed luctus nisl iaculis. Vivamus at neque arcu, sed tempor quam. Curabitur pharetra tincidunt tincidunt. Morbi volutpat feugiat mauris, quis tempor neque vehicula volutpat. Duis tristique justo vel massa fermentum accumsan. Mauris ante elit, feugiat vestibulum tempor eget, eleifend ac ipsum. Donec scelerisque lobortis ipsum eu vestibulum. Pellentesque vel massa at felis accumsan rhoncus.

Suspendisse commodo, massa eu congue tincidunt, elit mauris pellentesque orci, cursus tempor odio nisl euismod augue. Aliquam adipiscing nibh ut odio sodales et pulvinar tortor laoreet. Mauris a accumsan ligula. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Suspendisse vulputate sem vehicula ipsum varius nec tempus dui dapibus. Phasellus et est urna, ut auctor erat. Sed tincidunt odio id odio aliquam mattis. Donec sapien nulla, feugiat eget adipiscing sit amet, lacinia ut dolor. Phasellus tincidunt, leo a fringilla consectetur, felis diam aliquam urna, vitae aliquet lectus orci nec velit. Vivamus dapibus varius blandit.

Duis sit amet magna ante, at sodales diam. Aenean consectetur porta risus et sagittis. Ut interdum, enim varius pellentesque tincidunt, magna libero sodales tortor, ut fermentum nunc metus a ante. Vivamus odio leo, tincidunt eu luctus ut, sollicitudin sit amet metus. Nunc sed orci lectus. Ut sodales magna sed velit volutpat sit amet pulvinar diam venenatis.

Albert Einstein discovered that $e=mc^2$ in 1905.

\[ e=\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n \]

\makeletterclosing

\end{document}
```

[image]

And, with the help of the [`titletoc`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titletoc) package we can define a less intrusive ToC:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\@pnumwidth{1.55em}
\newcommand\@tocrmarg{2.55em}
\newcommand\@dotsep{4.5}
\makeatother
\usepackage{titletoc}

\makeatletter
\setlength\columnsep{20pt}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\newcommand\contentsname{Contents}
\newcommand\tableofcontents{%
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}}
\section*{\contentsname}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}}
    \@starttoc{toc}%
    }
\usepackage{titletoc}
\titlecontents*{section}[0pt]
  {}{}{}
  {, \itshape\thecontentspage}[\ \textbullet\ ][.]
\renewcommand\l@subsection[2]{}
\makeatother

\name{John}{Doe}
\title{Title}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle
\tableofcontents

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}  % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

\section{Master thesis}
\cvitem{title}{\emph{Title}}
\cvitem{supervisors}{Supervisors}
\cvitem{description}{Short thesis abstract}

\section{Experience}
\subsection{Vocational}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{General description no longer than 1--2 lines.\newline{}%
Detailed achievements:%
\begin{itemize}%
\item Achievement 1;
\item Achievement 2, with sub-achievements:
  \begin{itemize}%
  \item Sub-achievement (a);
  \item Sub-achievement (b), with sub-sub-achievements (don't do this!);
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Sub-sub-achievement i;
    \item Sub-sub-achievement ii;
    \item Sub-sub-achievement iii;
    \end{itemize}
  \item Sub-achievement (c);
  \end{itemize}
\item Achievement 3.
\end{itemize}}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{Description line 1\newline{}Description line 2}
\subsection{Miscellaneous}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{Description}

\section{Languages}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 1}{Skill level}{Comment}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 2}{Skill level}{Comment}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 3}{Skill level}{Comment}

\section{Computer skills}
\cvdoubleitem{category 1}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 4}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}
\cvdoubleitem{category 2}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 5}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}
\cvdoubleitem{category 3}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 6}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}

\section{Interests}
\cvitem{hobby 1}{Description}
\cvitem{hobby 2}{Description}
\cvitem{hobby 3}{Description}

\section{Extra 1}
\cvlistitem{Item 1}
\cvlistitem{Item 2}
\cvlistitem{Item 3. This item is particularly long and therefore normally spans over several lines. Did you notice the indentation when the line wraps?}

\section{Extra 2}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 1}{Item 4}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 2}{Item 5\cite{book1}}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 3}{Item 6. Like item 3 in the single column list before, this item is particularly long to wrap over several lines.}

\section{References}
\begin{cvcolumns}
  \cvcolumn{Category 1}{\begin{itemize}\item Person 1\item Person 2\item Person 3\end{itemize}}
  \cvcolumn{Category 2}{Amongst others:\begin{itemize}\item Person 1, and\item Person 2\end{itemize}(more upon request)}
  \cvcolumn[0.5]{All the rest \& some more}{\textit{That} person, and \textbf{those} also (all available upon request).}
\end{cvcolumns}

% Publications from a BibTeX file without multibib
%  for numerical labels: \renewcommand{\bibliographyitemlabel}{\@biblabel{\arabic{enumiv}}}% CONSIDER MERGING WITH PREAMBLE PART
%  to redefine the heading string ("Publications"): \renewcommand{\refname}{Articles}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{publications}                        % 'publications' is the name of a BibTeX file

% Publications from a BibTeX file using the multibib package
%\section{Publications}
%\nocitebook{book1,book2}
%\bibliographystylebook{plain}
%\bibliographybook{publications}                   % 'publications' is the name of a BibTeX file
%\nocitemisc{misc1,misc2,misc3}
%\bibliographystylemisc{plain}
%\bibliographymisc{publications}                   % 'publications' is the name of a BibTeX file

\clearpage
%-----       letter       ---------------------------------------------------------
% recipient data
\recipient{Company Recruitment team}{Company, Inc.\\123 somestreet\\some city}
\date{January 01, 1984}
\opening{Dear Sir or Madam,}
\closing{Yours faithfully,}
\enclosure[Attached]{curriculum vit\ae{}}          % use an optional argument to use a string other than "Enclosure", or redefine \enclname
\makelettertitle

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis ullamcorper neque sit amet lectus facilisis sed luctus nisl iaculis. Vivamus at neque arcu, sed tempor quam. Curabitur pharetra tincidunt tincidunt. Morbi volutpat feugiat mauris, quis tempor neque vehicula volutpat. Duis tristique justo vel massa fermentum accumsan. Mauris ante elit, feugiat vestibulum tempor eget, eleifend ac ipsum. Donec scelerisque lobortis ipsum eu vestibulum. Pellentesque vel massa at felis accumsan rhoncus.

Suspendisse commodo, massa eu congue tincidunt, elit mauris pellentesque orci, cursus tempor odio nisl euismod augue. Aliquam adipiscing nibh ut odio sodales et pulvinar tortor laoreet. Mauris a accumsan ligula. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Suspendisse vulputate sem vehicula ipsum varius nec tempus dui dapibus. Phasellus et est urna, ut auctor erat. Sed tincidunt odio id odio aliquam mattis. Donec sapien nulla, feugiat eget adipiscing sit amet, lacinia ut dolor. Phasellus tincidunt, leo a fringilla consectetur, felis diam aliquam urna, vitae aliquet lectus orci nec velit. Vivamus dapibus varius blandit.

Duis sit amet magna ante, at sodales diam. Aenean consectetur porta risus et sagittis. Ut interdum, enim varius pellentesque tincidunt, magna libero sodales tortor, ut fermentum nunc metus a ante. Vivamus odio leo, tincidunt eu luctus ut, sollicitudin sit amet metus. Nunc sed orci lectus. Ut sodales magna sed velit volutpat sit amet pulvinar diam venenatis.

Albert Einstein discovered that $e=mc^2$ in 1905.

\[ e=\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n \]

\makeletterclosing

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Which version of moderncv is this for? Couldn't make it work with 2.x

Comment: I would like to add subsections parts in the Table of Contents but I don't manage to do it. Do you have any idea? Thanks. Judikaël

Comment: @JudikaëlLeRouzo You have to use the non-stared version of \titlecontents (example in an answer below).

Answer (score 3):

I have modified Gonzalo's second option to show each content in a separate line:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\@pnumwidth{1.55em}
\newcommand\@tocrmarg{2.55em}
\newcommand\@dotsep{4.5}
\makeatother
\usepackage{titletoc}

\makeatletter
\setlength\columnsep{20pt}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\newcommand\contentsname{Contents}
\newcommand\tableofcontents{%
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}}
\section*{\contentsname}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}}
    \@starttoc{toc}%
    }
\usepackage{titletoc}
\titlecontents*{section}[0pt]
  {}{}{}
  {\hfill \thecontentspage \newline}[\ \newline\ ][]
\renewcommand\l@subsection[2]{}
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on Gonzalo’s 2nd option, here’s a version with subsections:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\@pnumwidth{1.55em}
\newcommand\@tocrmarg{2.55em}
\newcommand\@dotsep{4.5}
\makeatother
\usepackage{titletoc}

\makeatletter
\setlength\columnsep{20pt}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\newcommand\contentsname{Contents}
\newcommand\tableofcontents{%
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}}
    \section*{\contentsname}
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}}
    \@starttoc{toc}%
}
\titlecontents{section}[0pt]
{}{}{}
{, \itshape\thecontentspage}[]
\titlecontents{subsection}[20pt]
{}{}{}
{, \itshape\thecontentspage}[]
%\renewcommand\l@subsection[2]{}
\makeatother
```