# Creating a very custom ToC for moderncv

Tags: table-of-contents, moderncv

My university has a platform for job search which allows uploading only one curriculum vitae. However, I want to upload several curricula, each in a different language (I live in Europe and I speak three languages, and each of these has different conventions for curricula), so I came up with a big file (actually a master file with `docmute` and three files which can be compiled standalone) which has three curricula embedded, with invisible `\part` commands that provide ToC entries generation.
I have seen [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/158811/61789) and tried to mess with `titletoc`, obtaining a sort of classical LaTeX ToC, with hyperlink on part titles but not on page numbers.
But I'd rather like a ToC like

```
\section{Contents}
\cvitem{Page}{Language}
\cvitem{2}{Afrikaans}
\cvitem{3}{Zulu}
```

(obviously with some formatting, but for the moment hold on) and *both* the text and the page number hyperlinked.

The code I have so far is (more-or-less-Minimal WE):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,sans]{moderncv}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\name{John}{Doe}
\title{Bank magician}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

% For issuing \makecvtitle more than once
\patchcmd{\makecvtitle}{\newlength{\makecvtitledetailswidth}}{\let\makecvtitledetailswidth\relax\newlength{\makecvtitledetailswidth}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\makecvtitle}{\newlength{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}}{\let\makecvtitlepicturewidth\relax\newlength{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}}{}{}

\newcommand{\part}[1]{%
\clearpage%
\phantomsection%
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}%
}

\makeatletter % Table of Contents definition from Gonzalo Medina's answer
\newcommand\@pnumwidth{1.55em}
\newcommand\@tocrmarg{2.55em}
\newcommand\@dotsep{8}
\newcommand\contentsname{Contents}
\setlength\columnsep{20pt}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}
\newcommand\tableofcontents{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}}
  \newbox{\makecvtitlenamebox}
  \savebox{\makecvtitlenamebox}{%
    \namestyle{\@firstname\ \@lastname}%
  }
      \usebox{\makecvtitlenamebox}%
      \par\nobreak % don't break a page here
      \kern\the\prevdepth % don't take into account the depth of the preceding line
      \kern 4pt % space before the rule
  {   \color{gray!50}\hrule height 0.4ex width \textwidth } %1.05\wd\makecvtitlenamebox} % the rule
      \kern 0.75em % space after the rule
      \nointerlineskip % no additional space after the rule\hrule height 1ex width \wd\makecvtitlenamebox %
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\@title}{}}{}{\titlestyle{\@title}}%
  \vspace*{2\baselineskip}
  \section*{\contentsname}
  %\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}}
  \@starttoc{toc}%
  \clearpage
}

\usepackage{titletoc}
\titlecontents*{section}[0pt]
  {}{}{\textbullet}
  {\ \thecontentspage}[\\][]
\titlecontents{part}[0pt]
  {}{}{\hspace*{5em}\Large}
  {\leaders\hbox{\normalfont$\m@th\mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox{.}\mkern \@dotsep mu$}\hfill\Large\thecontentspage\hspace*{2em}}[]
\renewcommand\l@subsection[2]{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{Language 1}
\makecvtitle
\section{Section 1}
Some text
\part{Language 2}
\makecvtitle
\section{Section 1}
Some text
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that

```
\newcommand\l@part[2]{\cvitem{\tocpagefont #2}{\tocentryfont #1}}
\newcommand\l@section[2]{}
\newcommand\l@subsection[2]{}
```

with suitable formatting commands `\tocpagefont` and `\tocentryfont` does the job, without loading `titletoc`.
Next time I should read better `book.cls` :-)

For hyperlinking both the title and the number, just pass `linktoc=all` to `moderncv`: it will be passed to `hyperref`.