# Old moderncv template with hyperlinks in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, moderncv

For my application portfolio, I started from the template *bewerbungsmappe.zip* provided on [TU Graz miscellaneous templates](http://latex.tugraz.at/vorlagen/diverse). Only now I realized that this is based on an old version of the *moderncv.cls* . What I like about it is the separate cover page with a table of contents - defined from a separate *moderncv-additions.sty* included in the same zip folder. (That style file defines its own `\chapter` commands.) I haven't been able to add hyperlinks to the toc entries after numerous tries with `\AtEndPreamble{\hypersetup{...}}`
and also using `\phantomsection{}` before each chapter. The post [Add a table of contents into a moderncv document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/158803/add-a-table-of-contents-into-a-moderncv-document?noredirect=1&lq=1) is related but apparently based on a newer version of *moderncv.cls*. Can anyone give me a clue on how to get **clickable toc hyperlinks** in the old template and/or port the old template to a current version of moderncv? The latter might help me to sort out my problem based on the post linked above.

**Edit:** A MWE for my problem can be obtained from the zip file mentioned above as that folder is self-contained in terms of the old moderncv files.

**Edit 2:** Below the code from the *moderncv-additions.sty*. I guess for the toc hyperrefs to work, the commands for chapter and table of contents there have to be slightly modified. Any ideas?

```
% (c) 2010 Martin Weiglhofer <weiglhofer@ist.tugraz.at> and 
%          Thomas Quaritsch <t.quaritsch@student.tugraz.at>

\AtEndPreamble{

\renewcommand*{\contentsline}[4]{%
  #2 \dotfill #3\\
}

\newcommand{\makequote}{
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@quote}}%
  {}%
  {\centering{%
        \begin{minipage}{\quotewidth}\vspace*{2em}\centering\quotestyle{\@quote}\end{minipage}%
    }\\[2.5em]%
  }%
}

\newcommand{\chapter}{\@ifstar
                     \chapterStar
                     \chapterNoStar }

\newcommand*{\chapterNoStar}[2]{%
  {%
   \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1#2}%
   \chapter*{#1}{#2}%
  }%
}

\newcommand*{\chapterStar}[2]{%
  {%
    \hfill%
    {\raggedleft{\firstnamestyle{#1}\familynamestyle{#2}}\\[-.35em]}%
    {\color{firstnamecolor}\rule{\textwidth}{.25ex}\\[0.25em]}%
  }%
}

\renewcommand*{\@starttoc}[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \makeatletter
    \parskip\z@
    \@input{\jobname.#1}%
    \if@filesw
      \expandafter\newwrite\csname tf@#1\endcsname
      \immediate\openout \csname tf@#1\endcsname \jobname.#1\relax
    \fi
    \@nobreakfalse
  \endgroup
}
\def\tableofcontents{\@starttoc{toc}}

% usage: \section{<title>}
\renewcommand*{\section}[1]{%
  \vspace*{3ex plus 1ex minus 1ex}%
  \parbox[m]{\hintscolumnwidth}{\raggedleft\hintfont{\color{sectionrectanglecolor}\rule{\hintscolumnwidth}{1ex}}}%
  \phantomsection{}% reset the anchor for hyperrefs
  % \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}%
  \hspace{\separatorcolumnwidth}%
  \parbox[m]{\maincolumnwidth}{\sectionstyle{#1}}%
  \vspace*{3ex plus 1ex minus 1ex}%
}
%  \cvline[1ex]{\color{sectionrectanglecolor}\rule[0]{\hintscolumnwidth}{1ex}}{\sectionstyle{#1}}}% gives bad alignment of rectangle; too bad m{width} columns seem not to work as a valid column definition for tabular environments
% starred variant, which is identical but defined to allow its use (e.g. for natbib compatibility, who uses \section*{} for the bibliography header)

\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]%
  {%
    \subsection{\refname}%
%    \vspace*{-0.65em}%
    \small%
    \begin{list}{\bibliographyitemlabel}%
      {%
        \setlength{\topsep}{0pt}%
        \setlength{\labelwidth}{\hintscolumnwidth}%
        \setlength{\labelsep}{\separatorcolumnwidth}%
        \leftmargin\labelwidth%
        \advance\leftmargin\labelsep%
        \@openbib@code%
        \usecounter{enumiv}%
        \let\p@enumiv\@empty%
        \renewcommand\theenumiv{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
        \sloppy\clubpenalty4000\widowpenalty4000%
%        \sfcode`\.\@m%
%        \sfcode `\=1000\relax%
  }%
  {%
    \def\@noitemerr{\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
    \end{list}%
  }

}
```